# Reload persistent icon comming up on the top panel in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: icons, persistence

I upgraded my ubuntu to 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS. I start seeing the reload icon on my top panel. Could you help me with removing this? I believe it's something related to Gnome Extensions, though not sure.

[image]

Comment: You have plenty of extensions. The first thing to try is to disable them and re-enable them one by one until the issue appears again.

Comment: I figure it out that open weather extensions from gnome creating this issue. I have uninstalled the extension but still coming like this .. I don't know what should I do.

Comment: You probably did not correctly remove the extension if this still appears.